# CPoint only holds integer values for a points x and y? Alternatives?

Tags: c++, mfc

I am using the class `CPoint`. I am trying to, and successfully, passing doubles in the constructor for `CPoint`. After some testing I've found that `CPoint` holds its values as `LONG` which, following definitions, is defined as `typedef long LONG;` Which does help too much. But after reviewing the `CPoint` constructors

```
// create an uninitialized point
CPoint() throw();
// create from two integers
CPoint(int initX, int initY) throw();
// create from another point
CPoint(POINT initPt) throw();
// create from a size
CPoint(SIZE initSize) throw();
// create from an LPARAM: x = LOWORD(dw) y = HIWORD(dw)
CPoint(LPARAM dwPoint) throw();
```

It looks like it does hold its x and y values as `long`. ***Is there a predefined class/struct in C++ that holds floating point values for x and y points?***

Also, reviewing [this page](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/) from cplusplus about C++ variable types, it looks like there is a `long int` and a `long double`. How/why does (I think) the compiler infer that the `typedef long LONG` is a `long int` and not a `long double`?

Comment: `std::pair<long double, long double>` ? And `long` is a shortcut for `long int` when used alone.

Comment: Note that CPoint is not a standard C++ library class, it comes from MFC.

Comment: @Geoffroy can't I do something like `typedef std::pair... CFPoint`? But then how would I refer to "x" `CFPoint pnt; pnt .||->||?`

Comment: Looks like its `pnt.first` or `pnt->first`

Comment: @AnotherUser: It's just `.first`. Pointers would use `->` but `pair<X,Y>` is just two types of variables (often 2 different types) and entirely unrelated to pointers.

Comment: `CPoint` is designed to make using the `POINT` structure *easier*. If you are not using Windows API calls that require a `POINT`, don't use `CPoint`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`long` is interpreted as `long int` when used alone.

To hold to different values in standard C++ you can use `std::pair`:

```
typedef std::pair<long double, long double> point_t;
point_t t;
t.first = 10.0f;
t.second = -1.f;
```

For this precise case I'd prefer to define a special struct to hold the values, so you can add methods to it like operators:

```
struct point_t {
  long double x;
  long double y;

  point_t& operator+=(const point_t& rhs)
  { x += rhs.x; y += rhs.y; return *this; }

  // and so on
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`CPoint` is not predefined in C++ (it is provided by MFC library). C++ does not include any predefined classes for geometrical points.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the valid answers given by other, here is my input. If you must use `CPoint` (and `POINT`), you may derive a class from `CPoint` and provide your own constructor and/or operators that take or give floats and doubles. If you aren't doing client-area or GDI drawing, you may use custom class or `std::pair` class template.